# adding a custom route and setting it as root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have created the below routes.  I want to create an alternative to #show.  I have named this route 'users#current_user'.  How would I then set this new route to be the root url? However, I am being told the page does not exist.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I can provide more code if needed.

```
root 'users#current_user'
    resources :users do
       member do 
        get :current_user
       end 
        resources :posts
    end
```

I am getting the following message on the browser screen.  It does not seem to be recognizing my definition of the root URL.

-The page you were looking for doesn't exist-

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: I added some more detail to the post.  It does not seem to be recognizing the custom route set as the root url.

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

`bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

and try it again :)